# Convert vb6 Type to VB.net or C# Struct

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb6

I am converting an application originally written in vb6 to vb.net. One of the things this application does is that it sends a “Type” object to a dll. I tried converting the type to a structure and p/invoking the dll but it does not seem to work. I’ve been stuck for a week any help would be really appreciated

here is the vb6 code for the type

```
'Define WICS Communications Control Block (CCB).
Type WicsCCBType ' Create user-defined type.
    CCBNum As String * 1
    CCBVer As String * 1
    Resp1  As String * 4
    Resp2  As String * 4
    PLUA   As String * 8
    LLUA   As String * 8
    Mode   As String * 8
    ReqMax As String * 5
    ResMax As String * 5
End Type
```

and here is how the dll is called

```
Private Declare Sub WICSRASP Lib "wicsrasp.dll" (MyWicsCCB As WicsCCBType)
WICSRASP MyWicsCCB
```

this is what i tried with vb.net but it is not working

```
'Define WICS Communications Control Block (CCB).
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute( _
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, _
            CharSet:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.[Unicode])> _
    Structure WicsCCBType ' Create user-defined type.
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, sizeconst:=1)> Dim CCBNum As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, sizeconst:=1)> Dim CCBVer As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, sizeconst:=4)> Dim Resp1 As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, sizeconst:=4)> Dim Resp2 As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, sizeconst:=8)> Dim PLUA As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, sizeconst:=8)> Dim LLUA As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, sizeconst:=8)> Dim Mode As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, sizeconst:=5)> Dim ReqMax As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, sizeconst:=5)> Dim ResMax As String
    End Structure
```

and here is where i tried to call it

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("C:\windows\system32\wicsrasp.dll")> _
    Public Shared Sub WICSRASP(
                    ByRef CCB As WicsCCBType,
                    ByRef Request As DAWicsRequestType,
                    ByRef Response As DAWicsResponseType)
    End Sub

 Dim CCB As New modWICSDiary.WicsCCBType()
 CCB.CCBNum = "B"
            CCB.CCBVer = "2"
            CCB.LLUA = "        "
            CCB.Mode = "CICSMO2 "
            CCB.ReqMax = "2100 "
            CCB.ResMax = "2100 "
            CCB.Resp1 = "0   "
            CCB.Resp2 = "0   "
            CCB.PLUA = "WICSPLU "

  NativeMethods.WICSRASP(CCB)
```

As to the values, the same values work for the vb6 type

again thank you in advance

Comment: You need to try harder.  Provide how it is failing exactly.

Comment: To be honest, you should not be trying to create a .NET version of VB6 structure, you should be creating a .NET version of the C data structure that gets passed to WICSRASP.  If you had that documentation (say a header file) then this would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this has been solved by the OP yet, but here's my take on it.

Fixed-length strings inside UDTs in VB6 are not marshalled as pointers but are inlined into the structure.  Additionally, VB6 converts Unicode to Ansi before marshalling.  And VB6 uses 4 byte alignment.

The type will look this this in memory with the padding, with each successive field being named A through I in the illustration, and _ being a pad byte due to alignment.

```
CCBNum As String * 1     
|
|+-CCBVer As String * 1     
||
||  Resp1  As String * 4
||  |
||  |   Resp2  As String * 4     
||  |   |
||  |   |   PLUA   As String * 8     
||  |   |   |
||  |   |   |       LLUA   As String * 8     
||  |   |   |       |
||  |   |   |       |       Mode   As String * 8     
||  |   |   |       |       |
||  |   |   |       |       |       ReqMax As String * 5     
||  |   |   |       |       |       |
||  |   |   |       |       |       |       ResMax As String * 5 
||  |   |   |       |       |       |       |
||  |   |   |       |       |       |       |
VV  V   V   V       V       V       V       V

AB__CCCCDDDDEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGHHHHH___IIIII___
```

Therefore the CharSet should be Ansi, the StructAlignment should be 4.  The use of ByValTString is fine, as is the use of SizeConst.

Answer (score 1):

The VB6 will "marshal" all those string elements as ANSI strings. Change the Vb.Net marshalling code accordingly.

- Try `UnmanagedType.LPStr` in those `MarshalAs` attributes?
- Try changing the CharSet from Unicode to Ansi?
- Try `Pack=4` in the `StructLayoutAttribute`?

Useful link which explains the assumptions made by the VB6 [`Declare`](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp)

Comment: When I try that I get an exception (when I call the dll method) "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Comment: I think I was editing the answer when you posted that comment! Have you tried changing the Charset as well?

Comment: Try including `Pack=4` in your `StructLayoutAttribute`?

Comment: I made all 3 changes but i am still getting an "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt" error

Comment: @user889829 Fixed-length strings in a structure are not marshalled as pointers to a buffer, but inlined as part of a contiguous block of memory. Your original code was closer, but VB6 would have used Ansi strings and there may be 4-byte alignment going on as well.

Answer (score 0):

VB6 used BSTRs, didn't it? Shouldn't you marshal as BSTR?

Comment: No. VB6 converts Unicode to ANSI when calling a DLL with Declare. http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp

Comment: Just looked up my "Moving to VB.NET" by Dan Appleman. He says "In virtually every case where you call Win32 API functions that take string parameters, you'll declare the string ByVal As String... VB.NET pulls a fast one on the Declare statement... In other words, this is one place where VB.NET remains syntax compatible with VB6."

Comment: Summarising his more detailed explanation, apparently VB.NET makes a copy of the String before passing, even though you have declared ByVal.